# PDOExceptions and transactions

Tags: php, pdo, transactions

Lets say i have in mysql the following a table named "persons" that has two columns:
Name, idNumber. Both of them are the primary key.
The table is initially empty and i execute the following code:

```
try {
   $db->beginTransaction();

   $db->query("INSERT INTO persons (Name, idNumber) VALUES ('Alex', 10)";
   $db->query("INSERT INTO persons (Name, idNumber) VALUES ('John', 10)";
   $db->commit();

} catch (PDOException $e) {
    $db->rollBack();
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Ofcourse this should not work because we are inserting the same idNumber, 10, for two persons. My question is, will the error raised in MySQL after the 2nd insert be catched has an PDOException? If not, how can i stop the transaction if this sitaution happens? In php code.

Comment: why don't you run it and try it out? Of course, you'd have had to ENABLE exceptions in PDO to begin with. By default PDO uses ERRMODE_SILENT and doesn't signal ANY errors.

Comment: You need to try it. This said, i use prepared statement and test this: if ($sth->execute()){} where $sth os your $db. you can test the query i suppose and if not (false) you can obtain the error

Comment: I did try it, turns out i receive an warning:

Warning: PDO::query(): SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062

But, the first insert is done, and the second isnt. What i want is, if one fails, rollback and do not insert none, and that is not happening

Comment: Got it to work with: PDO::ERRMODE_Exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just set PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION in the initial $db inicialization.

$db = new PDO("mysql:host="....., array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));